# Proper Method for updating Game difficulty

Tags: actionscript-3, timer, flash-cs6

Hey everyone I was wondering what would be the best method to go about updating my games difficulty. So the more points you get I want the timer objects on stage to decrease to a lower number so the enemies can come out quicker and there will be more on stage I have my main function that handles this called `updateDifficulty();`

in my constructor I start the timers to their default tick values then change them in that function like so:

```
    private function updateDifficulty():void 
    {
        if (difficultyUpdate) return;

        if (nScore >= 100)
        {


            tSeagullTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addSeagull);
            tSeagullTimer.stop();

            tSeagullTimer = new Timer(8000);
            //listen for the timer
            tSeagullTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addSeagull, false, 0, true);
            tSeagullTimer.start();

            difficultyUpdate = true;
        }

        difficultyUpdate = false;
        if (nScore >= 300 && bombBoolean)
        { 

            addBomb();
            bombBoolean = false

            tSeagullTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addSeagull);
            tSharkTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addShark);
            tSeagullTimer.stop();
            tSharkTimer.stop();

            tSharkTimer = new Timer(4000);
            //Listen for timer intervals/ticks
            tSharkTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addShark,false,0,true);
            //Start timer object
            tSharkTimer.start();

            tSeagullTimer = new Timer(6000);
            //listen for the timer
            tSeagullTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addSeagull, false, 0, true);
            tSeagullTimer.start();

           difficultyUpdate = true;
        }
```

}

it works for the most part but sometimes I see that the timers stop working from time to time. Is there a better way of changing the timer value?

Answer (score 1):

see this part:

```
    if (nScore >= 100)
    {
        //...skip...
        difficultyUpdate = true;
    }

    difficultyUpdate = false;
    if (nScore >= 300 && bombBoolean)
    {
        //...skip...
```

"difficultyUpdate = true" in the first block will be always overwritten by "difficultyUpdate = false" right after it.

I don't know if this is the cause but it is an obvious error anyway.

Also I would put these blocks in different order. First, the block with bigger score, next the block with smaller score, and put a return statement in each of them. Obviously if Score > 300, you don't need to check the Score > 100 part.

Also I would't use Timers. I'd just use counters inside a Event.ENTER_FRAME handler which you should already have. So it would look like:

```
// (inside your Event.ENTER_FRAME handler)
if (seagullTickCount) {
    seagullTickCount--;
} else {
    addSeagull();
    seagullTickCount = getSeagullTickCount(); // here you will use difficulty
}
```

Further, it's not good to have a separate function for each tick count, but I used it just for illustration purposes.